# Automatic screen rotation - always upside down

Tags: windows-10, tablet

I have a GoClever Insignia 800 Win tablet. It was using Windows 8.1 when stock, and after it got upgraded to Windows 10, the automatic screen rotation got broken - it always rotates so the image is upside down.

I have tried performing a clean Windows 10 install (since the factory Windows 8.1 installation was pretty bad and I didn't care about it whatsoever). Unfortunately, the issue was not fixed.

Is there a way to re-teach Windows which way is "up"?

Comment: can you make pictures? I currently don't know what you mean.

Comment: @magicandre1981, everything was upside down (I already solved the problem), as if you hold a book upside down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by taking apart the driver installer script. The problem is caused by part of the script not executing properly - apart from installing the drivers themselves, the script is also intended to set up a couple registry keys. Unfortunately, this part of the script doesn't execute at all, which is why the screen rotation feature is not configured - therefore not working properly.

All I had to do is to create a .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\SENSOR\0000\Device Parameters\kxfusion]
"ACPI\\SMO8500\\1-0"="{E7AD1D74-B2BF-47B4-9FCD-EA67A2EEFE3A}"
"Orientation"=hex:01,01,01,01,00,00,02
```

and import it into registry.

Comment: Notice that this string is dynamic : "ACPI\\SMO8500\\1-0"="{E7AD1D74-B2BF-47B4-9FCD-EA67A2EEFE3A}" ,
Better to do it manually in regedit.

Comment: For Toshiba wtc-7 the orientation is: 01 01 00 01 01 01 02. this is the Kionix sensor.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-enable this feature, go trough the next steps.

- Go to the Desktop App.
- Right Click (using the mouse, or touching and holding until the Square appears).
- Click on Screen Resolution.
- Check to see if Allow the screen to auto-rotate is checked
  -Ensure that Orientation is set to Landscape.

*Source:* http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/my-tablet-no-longer-senses-landscape-screen/97212718-f1d4-49b9-ae22-aafdf5d16b7d?auth=1

Comment: It does rotate and switch between portrait and landscape properly. The problem is that the picture is always upside-down.